# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `currency' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a piece of code that looks like this;

```
<% @current_user.prices.each_with_index do | t, i| %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%= (i+1) %> </td> 
        <td> <%= t.country %> </td>
        <td> <%= t.network %> </td>
        <td> <%= t.send("price_#{@current_user.currency.downcase}") %> </td>
    </tr>       
<% end %>
```

but it gives the error;

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `currency' for nil:NilClass):
    30:                             <td> <%= (i+1) %> </td> 
    31:                             <td> <%= t.country %> </td>
    32:                             <td> <%= t.network %> </td>
    33:                             <td> <%= t.send("price_#{@current_user.currency.downcase}")  %> </td>
    34:                         </tr>       
    35:                     <% end %>
    36:                 <% else %>
  app/views/prices/index.html.erb:33:in `block in _app_views_prices_index_html_erb__1511544251155426207_16153880'
  app/views/prices/index.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_prices_index_html_erb__1511544251155426207_16153880'
```

However, in a very similar circumstance it works just fine;

```
<% @current_user.prices.each_with_index do | t, i| %>
    <tr>
       <td> <%= (i+1) %> </td> 
       <td> <%= t.country %> </td>
       <td> <%= t.network %> </td>
       <td> <%= t.send("price_#{@current_user.currency.downcase}") %> </td>
   </tr>
```

How come it works in one one scenario but not another? Maybe am just tired anyway.

Comment: you have two completely identical pieces of code at the top and at the bottom of your question. what is the reason for that?

Comment: Your `@current_user` was `nil` in those circumstances. Chances are you've forgotten to assign it in controller. And yes, I can't see the differences between the two only but forgotten `<% end %>` that should end up as a syntax error.

Comment: If @current_user is nil when `.currency` is called on it, that's a little weird, because it would have been nil when `.prices` was called on it. As you sure you've copy and pasted your code? If you've typed it in here, you might have not duplicated an typo/error in your code. Alternatively, something might be resetting @current_user (to nil) in the other method calls your making.

Answer (score 0):

for one user it has some value other then nil and for current user the value of currency is nil that why this error arises you can check using console or apply break point and check for current user currency value

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `@current_user` variable is nil, and you are calling currency for that nil object.

**SOLUTION**

If you just want to skip this error then you can use `try()` like below code.

Example:

```
@current_user.try(:currency).try(:downcase)
# try() behaves something like ternary operator (if then else)
```

But, I suggest you to assign `@current_user` with your required value. Because if you will use `try()`, It will return nil, if the parent object is nil. So, debug your `@current_user` variable and assign it with correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`@current_user.currency.downcase` did not work because the the `index controller` is not authenticated with devise and therefore `@current_user` is not defined.

However, i cannot explain why it was defined a few lines above this line.